# Get Checkbox value for edit data PHP

Tags: php, html, checkbox

```
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="checked_id[]" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id_student;?>"/></td>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" onClick="window.location = 'edit.php?ktp=<?php echo $id_student; ?>'">EDIT</button
```

How can i get the value of the checkbox for use on other php page like `edit.php`? `Id_student = 3454`? My results may differ from the checkbox value I choose.

Comment: Would have to use AJAX with jquery or a php post/get scenario.  What are you trying to do? Check a student then go to an edit page? Why don't you just make that a link to the edit page with that student's id?  You can't go to more than one edit page at a time and using checkboxes you can select more than one. You should either use links or radio buttons

Comment: thx for advice. i will try now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure i understand your question clearly, but from what i understood i hope this example helps

```
$.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ajax/checkbox.php',
    data: { foton : $('input:checkbox:checked').val()},

    success: function(data) {
        $('#message').html(data);
    }
} );
```

```
/ajax/checkbox.php?name=foton
```

Here you have a `$_GET` parameter that's called `name` and its **value** is `foton`.

you sebd the value of your checkbox in a `$_POST` **parameter** called `foton`.

You don't have to set a query string in your `$.ajax` url when you specify data (instead of you **want** to redirect to a page which will process your `$_GET` parameters a part).